# Please, help me to understand the snippet from the "Programming Perl" book

Tags: perl, perl-context

I read the "Programming Perl" by By Tom Christiansen, brian d foy, Larry Wall, Jon Orwant. There is the following text which I failed to understand (the exact places which I do not understand are marked with bold):

> What you really want to know is which operators supply which context
>   to their operands. As it happens, you can easily tell which ones
>   supply list context because **they all have LIST in their syntactic
>   descriptions**. Everything else supplies scalar context. Generally,
>   it’s quite intuitive. If necessary, you can **force scalar context
>   onto an argument in the middle of a LIST** by using the `scalar`
>   pseudofunction. Perl provides no way to force list context in context,
>   because anywhere you would want list context **it’s already provided
>   by the LIST** of some controlling function.

For convenience I would like to formulate the following questions:

1. What does it mean **LIST** in the snippet?
2. What is **syntactic description**? (seems to be a some sort of documentation)
3. What does it mean the next text:

> you can **force scalar context
>   onto an argument in the middle of a LIST**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's quite simple, like the text says. Take a look at `perldoc -f print` for example:

```
print FILEHANDLE LIST
print FILEHANDLE
print LIST
```

Like it says right there, `print` takes LIST arguments, meaning anything posted after `print` is in list context. It is the same for any function where the argument(s) are denoted as LIST.

With the `scalar` function, you can override this list context, so that your argument is *not* evaluated in list context. For example, a file handle readline statement such as:

```
my $line = <$fh>;
```

Is evaluated in scalar context, because `$line` is a scalar. This means only one line is read and put into the variable. However, if you were to do:

```
print <$fh>;
```

The readline is in list context, which means all remaining lines in the file will be read. You can override this by putting the readline statement in scalar context:

```
print scalar <$fh>;
```

And then you will just read one line. To be more precise, you can enforce scalar context *in the middle* of a list:

```
print @list, scalar <$fh>, @list2;
```

Which presumably is what is referred to in that quote of yours.